# ImageMagick convert exit status 133

Tags: java, permissions, imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick's convert tool to convert images from within my Java program running on Mac OS X.
I am using the following code, which I adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148043/problem-with-imagemagick-and-java-runtime-exec).

```
public static void convertToJPG(String originalFile, String newFile) throws Exception {
    executeCommand("/usr/local/ImageMagick-6.6.7/bin/convert", originalFile, newFile);
}

private static void executeCommand(String... command) throws Exception {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    int exitStatus = p.waitFor();
    System.out.println(exitStatus);
    if(exitStatus != 0)
        throw new Exception("Error converting image.");
}
```

However, when I do this, I get an exit status of **133** and the error message below. I am assuming that this has something to do with permissions, as when I run the same command from the terminal, it works fine.

**Error message:**

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /ImageMagick-6.6.7/lib/libMagickCore.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/ImageMagick-6.6.7/bin/convert
  Reason: image not found
```

**Edit:** Ok, so it turns out that I was getting the above error message due to Java not being able to see the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. So I restarted Eclipse and everything worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I wasn't able to find anything about a 133 return code, I did notice that you aren't reading the command standard out / standard error stream. I'd suggest reading that to see if ImageMagick is giving you some more helpful output. There's a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808276/how-to-add-a-timeout-value-when-using-javas-runtime-exec) that deals with more complex use cases of the Runtime.exec() method, but the best basic way to do it is [with this method](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4).

Comment: Wow, that makes perfect sense, can't believe I didn't think of it. Thank you! I'll try that today.

Answer (score 4):

Return code 133 = 128 + 5 = <terminated by signal> + SIGTRAP

See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html
and the output of "kill -l".

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [jmagick](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmagick) which provides a Java API to the native imagemagick libraries. It's more efficient than spawning new processes from your Java app.

Comment: I did consider that, but I read somewhere that if I wasn't going to be using ImageMagick much (in my case, only one or two convert commands), then it would be easier to just do it this way.